# ¿Cómo hago para pausar una canción y luego reproducir otra usando MediaPlayer en una misma activity?

Tags: android-studio, activity, mediaplayer

He intentado de todo, de hecho obviamente ya intente poner la canción en pause y darle start a la otra, pero me sale un error en la aplicación : "app se detuvo"
es decir se cae la app.

Lo que necesito es que al suceder una condición se pause o se detenga la canción que se inicia con la activity y se inicie la otra canción, teniendo en cuenta que al salir de la app se detenga la canción en curso y que al iniciarse regrese donde estaba.

Este es el código de mi activity:

```
public class Comenzar extends Activity {
public static MediaPlayer primeraronda,segundaronda;

    Button r1,r2,r3,r4;
    static TextView npregunta;
    TextView preguntas,nivelactual;
    ImageView fotoperfil;


    @Override
    protected void onCreate(Bundle savedInstanceState) {
        super.onCreate(savedInstanceState);
        setContentView(R.layout.activity_comenzar);
        primeraronda=MediaPlayer.create(this, R.raw.primerronda);
        primeraronda.setLooping(true);
        primeraronda.start();
        preguntas=(TextView)findViewById(R.id.preguntas);
        nivelactual=(TextView)findViewById(R.id.nivelactual);
        fotoperfil=(ImageView)findViewById(R.id.fotoperfil);
        r1 = (Button) findViewById(R.id.respuesta1);
        r2 = (Button) findViewById(R.id.respuesta2);
        r3 = (Button) findViewById(R.id.respuesta3);
        r4 = (Button) findViewById(R.id.respuesta4);
        npregunta = (TextView) findViewById(R.id.npregunta);

        r1.setOnClickListener(new View.OnClickListener() {
            @Override
            public void onClick(View v) {
                Intent i4 = new Intent(Comenzar.this, popup.class);
                Intent i3 = new Intent(Comenzar.this, popupc.class);
                Intent i5 = new Intent(Comenzar.this, terminar.class);
                if (npregunta.getText().toString().equals("2")){
                startActivityForResult(i3,1);
                }
                else if(npregunta.getText().toString().equals("7")){

                    startActivity(i5);
                }
                else {

                    startActivity(i4);
                }
            }
        });

        r2.setOnClickListener(new View.OnClickListener() {
            @Override
            public void onClick(View v) {
                Intent i4 = new Intent(Comenzar.this, popup.class);
                Intent i3 = new Intent(Comenzar.this, popupc.class);
                if (npregunta.getText().toString().equals("1") || npregunta.getText().toString().equals("1")){
                    startActivityForResult(i3,1);
                }
                else {

                    startActivity(i4);
                }
            }
        });

        r3.setOnClickListener(new View.OnClickListener() {
            @Override
            public void onClick(View v) {
                Intent i4 = new Intent(Comenzar.this, popup.class);
                Intent i3 = new Intent(Comenzar.this, popupc.class);
                if (npregunta.getText().toString().equals("3") || npregunta.getText().toString().equals("6")
                        || npregunta.getText().toString().equals("8")){
                    startActivityForResult(i3,1);
                }
                else {

                    startActivity(i4);
                }
            }
        });

        r4.setOnClickListener(new View.OnClickListener() {
            @Override
            public void onClick(View v) {
                Intent i4 = new Intent(Comenzar.this, popup.class);
                Intent i3 = new Intent(Comenzar.this, popupc.class);
                if (npregunta.getText().toString().equals("4") || npregunta.getText().toString().equals("5")){
                    startActivityForResult(i3,1);
                }
                else {

                    startActivity(i4);
                }
            }
        });

    }


@Override
    protected void onActivityResult(int peticion, int codigo, Intent data) {
       super.onActivityResult(peticion,codigo,data);
        if(peticion==1 && codigo==RESULT_OK){

            String resultado=data.getStringExtra("tpregunta");
            npregunta.setText(resultado);

            if(resultado.equals("6")){
                if ( primeraronda.isPlaying())
                {primeraronda.stop();
                    segundaronda=MediaPlayer.create(this, R.raw.crimson);
                    segundaronda.start();
                }



            }

        }

    }



    @Override
    protected  void onPause(){

        super.onPause();
       primeraronda.pause();
       segundaronda.pause();
    }
    @Override
    protected void onResume(){

        super.onResume();
        primeraronda.start();
       segundaronda.start();

    }
    @Override
    protected void onDestroy(){

        super.onDestroy();
        if (primeraronda.isPlaying()){
            primeraronda.stop();
            primeraronda.release();}
        if    (segundaronda.isPlaying()){
               segundaronda.stop();
                segundaronda.release();
        }
    }

}
```

Este es el código de mi popupc que es la activity que trae el resultado que ven en la activity comenzar:

```
public class popupc extends Activity {

    Button continuar;
    private int bandera=1;
    @Override
    protected void onCreate(Bundle savedInstanceState) {
        super.onCreate(savedInstanceState);
        bandera=Integer.parseInt(Comenzar.npregunta.getText().toString());
        //Bundle extras=getIntent().getExtras();
        setContentView(R.layout.activity_popupc);
        DisplayMetrics dm= new DisplayMetrics();
        getWindowManager().getDefaultDisplay().getMetrics(dm);
        continuar=(Button)findViewById(R.id.continuar);
        int width=dm.widthPixels;
        int height=dm.heightPixels;
        getWindow().setLayout((int)(width*.8),(int)(height*.6));
        Comenzar.primeraronda.start();
        Comenzar.segundaronda.start();
        continuar.setOnClickListener(new View.OnClickListener() {
            @Override
            public void onClick(View v) {
                bandera++;
                String tpregunta=Integer.toString(bandera);
                Intent data=new Intent();
                data.putExtra("tpregunta",tpregunta);
                setResult(RESULT_OK,data);
                finish();
            }
        });


    }


}
```

Comment: Porque no agregas el mensaje de error del LogCat a tu pregunta. También recuerda que no necesitas crear más instancias de mediaPlayer para reproducir los demás audios. @JohanBerrio

Comment: No tengo emulador porque mi pc no soporta virtualización entonces no lo puedo compilar en mi pc sino que siempre ensayo la app en mi telefono directamente, entonces no puedo usar los mensajes del logcat. Y como hago para reproducir los demas audios sin crear mas instancias?